# Can I avoid illgealAccessException when checking if Class private fields are null or empty?

Tags: java, checked-exceptions

This is the block of code inside the boolean method that I want to check if there are any empty or null fields. It returns true if none of them are. If they are, it throws a custom exception for each case, but it messes up my entire program when it makes me throw the IllegalAccessException.

```
for(Field f: getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        if((f.get(this)) == null) {
            throw new NullValueException("Error, this book has null value");
        }
        if(f.get(this).toString().isEmpty()) {
            throw new ItemEmptyException("Error, this book has null value");
        }
    }catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Even if I use `f.setAccessible(true)`, it still makes me use try-catch clause for the exception.
Can I avoid that try-catch clause and never have to throw an IllegalAccessException?

Comment: If you're calling a method that declares it may throw a checked exception, then you have to indicate how the exception will be handled; or declare that your method will throw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler looks at the declaration of the methods you use. If a method is declared to (possibly) throw a checked exception, the caller must either handle that exception or declare to throw it as well, delegating exception handling to their caller. In your example you call `f.setAccessible(true);` so you probably won't encounter a `IllegalAccessException`, but the compiler does not know this.

In your code, I'd add a comment to the catch block stating why this should never happen (you set the fields to accessible).

If you don't want to burden your callers with dealing with `IllegalAccessException`s, throw something else instead. If it's really virtually impossible that your code triggers a `IllegalAccessException`, you could throw an unchecked exception like `IllegalStateException`, or use an `assert` to indicate that something went really unexpectedly wrong.